# Is it possible to connect any RDBMS through spark usinig java?

Tags: java, apache-spark

```
            JdbcRDD rdd = new org.apache.spark.rdd.JdbcRDD(
                    sparkConf,
                    ()= > {
                        Class.forName ("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
    sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://mysql.example.com/?user=batman&password=alfred")
  },
  "SELECT * FROM BOOKS WHERE ? <= KEY AND KEY <= ?",
  0, 1000, 10,
  row =  > row.getString("BOOK_TITLE")
         )
```

I tried above scala code changing classes to  java 8,but so many errors coming.

Comment: Post your actual code and errors so we can help.

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem before, it turns out it's the problem of SQL parameters, basically you need to use sql like:
`sql
select * from books limit ?, ?`

the two parameters for `lowerBound` and `upperBound` which are required by JdbcRdd constructor.

Comment: are you able to connect any rdbms using spark ? if yes,please help me with code snippet.